# Soap message name space issue on tomcat server

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soap, spring-boot

Hi I have a problem for quite some time that I can not solve. When I run my application on STS spring with spring run boot command, everything works fine. But if I try to deploy application on tomcat, everything works except the addition of a namespace to a soap message that reject the call to the soap service.

I insert below correct soap message on spring boot and follow the wrong message on tomcat.

SPING BOOT SUCCESS SOAP MSG:

```
<RetrieveDocumentSetRequest 
xmlns="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007" 
xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0"
xmlns:ns3="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0" 
xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:lcm:3.0" 
xmlns:ns5="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0">
<DocumentRequest>
<RepositoryUniqueId>2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.2.999.4.5.113883</RepositoryUniqueId>
<DocumentUniqueId>2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.2.999.4.4^123456</DocumentUniqueId></DocumentRequest>
</RetrieveDocumentSetRequest>
```

TOMCAT 7 FAIL SOAP MSG:

```
   <ns6:RetrieveDocumentSetRequest 
xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0"
xmlns:ns3="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0" 
xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:lcm:3.0" 
xmlns:ns5="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0"
xmlns:ns6="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007">
<DocumentRequest><RepositoryUniqueId>2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.2.999.4.5.113883</RepositoryUniqueId>
<DocumentUniqueId>2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.2.999.4.4^123456</DocumentUniqueId>
</DocumentRequest>
</ns6:RetrieveDocumentSetRequest>
```

As you can see messages are almost same except for n6 namespace. I can't understand why and if there is a wrong Jar on tomcat respect to springboot sever.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. 
The generator classes specified in the pom.xml of spring boot, using JAXB to generate classes from the interface WSDL, while the Jar that use and release of tomcat, using jax-ws library for generations of classes starting from WSDL. 
The first library, JAXB, insert the annotation regarding the namespace, both on classes properties and inner classes of the generated classes. All this does not happen when using jax-ws, but only for some classes. This thing even if at first sight irrelevant, creates an answer rejected by the validator server side, the SOAP request sent.

I hope it will help someone in the future.